# Paint peeled on fascia board, how to get paint to stick?

Tags: painting, paint, repainting, patch, fascia

I sanded, primed, then painted one of my fascia boards, and most of the board dried fine, just one part where there’s wood filler and silicone calking is where the paint peeled.

How can I fix this area where the paint peeled, and get the paint to stick? What steps would I need to take to patch it properly?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Paint will not stick to silicone.

You will need to sand it all off, be sure you do not leave any silicon on the board.

If you need to do more patching use an exterior [Vinyl patching compound](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DAP-32-oz-White-Spackling/3964011)

Patch, sand , prime   and paint.

Comment: Exactly correct!

Comment: Why vinyl patch if the surface I’m patching is wood? What kind of patching product should I use?

Comment: @eclipsis  the link was not working I edited it to link to the product intended

Comment: There's also acrytlc and urethane based caulks that are paintable.